# Fields from Salesforce Object not available in Marketing Cloud Import Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm trying to create an Import Activity in Marketing Cloud to import fields from a Salesforce Custom Object, however I note that some fields are missing. If you refer to the screenshot below, you will note that there is no 'Attended__c' custom field.

[image: Import Activity]

However, this field is included in the Custom Object in Salesforce Sales Cloud:

[image: Fields and Relationships]

Do you know why this field (and others) do not appear in the available fields within the Import Activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only Salesforce Object fields with the appropriate **Field-Level Security** settings are available through Marketing Cloud Connect (formerly the 'v5 Connector').

You will need to set the Field-Level Security as described in this brief [video tutorial](http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/ExFZudjhquI28XE5o2tZxQ).

Enable the 'visible' checkbox for the **Sys Admin** account for the respective field:

[image: Field-Level Security]

This field will now be available for the respective Object when creating a new Import Activity in Marketing Cloud.

**Sidenote:** It appears that Rich Text Area fields in Salesforce Objects are not available for use in the Marketing Cloud Import Activity.

Comment: **Update:** I have been informed that Rich Text Area fields can be imported [using Data Stream](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/integrating_data_into_your_account_with_data_stream/) but not from an Import Activity.